# ASP.NET click event confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick

I'm really confused. . In `ASP.NET`, to capture a click event in `C#`, would I use `runat="server"` and `onclick="emnt_Click()"`, or `elmt.onclick = elmt_Click()`, or `elmt.Attributes.Add("onclick","elmt_Click()"`, or just have this:

```cs
private void elmt_Click()
{
    // Code
}
```

Do they all work?

I'm really confused. :(

Please help :):):)

Comment: "Do they all work?" surely you could just try each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your aspx page you can hook up an onclick event with `OnClick="elmt_Click"` (provided it's inside a form). For example:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="elmt_Click" Text="Submit" />
```

Alternatively in your code behind file, you can hook up the onclick event by adding the following in your `page_load` method:

```
elmt_Click.Click += elmt_Click; // Note the Plus and equal sign
```

In your code behind you can the create the event as:

```
protected void elmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

The `onclick` event needs to be accessible to the aspx page. Therefore `private` will need to be changed to `protected` or `public`. Also the method will need to pass in `sender` and `EventArgs`.

`elmt.Attributes.Add()` will only add a html attribute to a tag and will not wire up an ASP.NET event.

Documentation for ASP.NET button can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: What about elements without `asp:`? If they still have `runat=server`, does it still work?

Comment: yes, so you can add it to a html input. However you'll need to change "OnClick" with "onserverclick". Also if you want to add the onclick via the code behind, you'll need to change "Click" to ServerClick. E.g: elmt_Click.ServerClick+= elmt_Click;